# Is there exist an Euler graph on 2014 vertices with 3007 edges?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I have to prove or disprove the statement "there exist an Euler graph on 2014 vertices with 3007 edges"

here is my argument

let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=2014, |E|=3007$

let $v_i\in V (i=1,2\dots2014)$ and suppose $deg(v_i)=2m_i$ wehere $m_i\in \Bbb N$

by handshaking lemma

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2014}deg(v_i)=2\cdot3007$

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2014}2m_i=2\cdot3007$

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2014}m_i=3007$

now by taking some sequence of $m_i$ which has the property $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2014}m_i=3007$ gives me a Euler graph.since degree of every vertex is even.

am I correct or wrong? if i am correct is there any better way to prove this?if i am wrong how should i prove?any hint?

Comment: The most convincing way to show that such a graph exists would be to provide a description of one concrete example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the "union" of the two cyclic graphs 
$$0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - \cdots - 2013 - 0
\quad\text{ and }\quad
0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - \cdots - 1984 - 0$$ 
It has $2014$ vertices and $(2013+1)+(\frac{1984}{2}+1) = 3007$ edges.

Start at vertex $0$, first walks around the first graph, next 
walks around second graph and finally back to $0$ give us an Euler circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong or incomplete.

You have to show that such a sequence $\{m_i\}$ exists, i.e. the sequence $\{2 m_i\}$ is graphical. Not all sequences will give valid graphs.

Comment: This answer assumes you're working with simple connected graphs (multigraphs are easier to check for graphical-ness).

Comment: yes.. I got it.